# PQRS is a rhombus. Given that $\overrightarrow{PQ}=a$ and $ \overrightarrow{QR}=b$.

Tags: vectors

PQRS is a rhombus. Given that $\overrightarrow{PQ}=a$ and $
\overrightarrow{QR}=b$.

(a) express the vectors $\overrightarrow{PR}$ and $
\overrightarrow{QS}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

(b) hence show that the diagonals in a rhombus intersect at right 
angles.

My Attempt:

(a) $\overrightarrow{PR}=a+b$ and $\overrightarrow{QS}=b-a
$

I have no idea how to work out part (b). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: now show that $\overrightarrow{PR} \cdot \overrightarrow{QS}=0$

Comment: @Vasya, Please check my comment below.

Comment: you'll get $-\overrightarrow{a}\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\overrightarrow{b}=0$ because both vectors have the same magnitude (this is rhombus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the dot product of diagonals, that is 0( because b=a), hence proved.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am stuck where (a+b).(b-a)=0, how do you proceed from there? Please provide a detailed explanation, because I do not understand how b = a will help here.

Comment: Multiplication of vectors is like numbers and all algebraic identities hold because of commutativity of dot product

Comment: $(\vec a+\vec b)(\vec b-\vec a)=\vec a\vec b-\vec a\vec a+\vec b\vec b-\vec b\vec a$. For dot product $\vec a\vec b=\vec b\vec a$ and $\vec a \vec a=a^2$